# window resizing in kubuntu 16.04 (again)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu, opengl

I get an immortal issue. It is a window resizing. It is so laggy when I use OpenGL 3.0 or OpenGL 2.1 as an enging in settings. I mean the option in Systemsettings -> Display -> Effects -> Rendering Backend. When I use XRender it is not laggy but I used OpenGL 3.1 at kubuntu 14.04. What's happened? Also I have asked my friend about this issue on his computer. He doesn't get it. He uses OpenGL 3.1 and doesn't have the issue.

Please help me to fix it.

My pc configuration:
**AMD FX-6300, GeForce 760 GTX (2GB, 256-bit), 16GB RAM 1800 MHz.**

My friend pc configuration:
**AMD FX-8300, GeForce 960 GTX (4GB, 128-bit), 16GB RAM 1800 MHz.**

I use plasma 5.8.7

My **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 384.69  (buildd@lgw01-37)  Wed Aug 23 01:05:31 UTC 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AOC 2778X"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 99.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 760"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

My **/var/log/Xorg.0.log**

```
[    32.060] (--) Log file renamed from "/var/log/Xorg.pid-1363.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
[    32.060] 
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
[    32.060] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    32.060] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    32.060] Current Operating System: Linux microlab 4.4.0-93-generic #116-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 11 21:17:51 UTC 2017 x86_64
[    32.061] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic root=UUID=7e28db9a-0b30-4979-927a-09ba4ba6879a ro
[    32.061] Build Date: 17 July 2017  05:05:12PM
[    32.061] xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    32.061] Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
[    32.061]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    32.061] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    32.061] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Sep  2 18:25:24 2017
[    32.147] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    32.147] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    32.165] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[    32.165] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[    32.165] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[    32.174] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[    32.174] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[    32.174] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[    32.174] (**) Option "Xinerama" "0"
[    32.174] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    32.174] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    32.174] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    32.174] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    32.174] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    32.174]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    32.174] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    32.174]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    32.174] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    32.174]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    32.174] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[    32.174] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    32.174] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[    32.174] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[    32.174] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[    32.355] (II) Loader magic: 0x99577bddc0
[    32.355] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    32.355]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    32.355]    X.Org Video Driver: 20.0
[    32.355]    X.Org XInput driver : 22.1
[    32.355]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
[    32.355] (++) using VT number 7

[    32.355] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[    32.355] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    32.357] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:1187:1462:2848 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfd000000/16777216, 0xf0000000/134217728, 0xf8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000dc00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    32.357] (II) "glx" will be loaded. This was enabled by default and also specified in the config file.
[    32.357] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    32.357] (II) Module "dbe" already built-in
[    32.357] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    32.357] (II) Module "extmod" already built-in
[    32.357] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    32.362] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    34.124] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    34.124]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.124]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    34.124] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  384.69  Wed Aug 16 19:34:06 PDT 2017
[    34.124] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    34.124] (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    34.304] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    34.336]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.336]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    34.362] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  384.69  Wed Aug 16 19:07:09 PDT 2017
[    34.362] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    34.371] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    34.371] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    34.376] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    34.385] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.385]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.385]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.385] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    34.385] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    34.385] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    34.389] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    34.389]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    34.389]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    34.389] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    34.389] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    34.389] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    34.392] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    34.392] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    34.392] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    34.392] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "Stereo" "0"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "SLI" "Off"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MultiGPU" "Off"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "BaseMosaic" "off"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Stereo disabled by request
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA SLI disabled.
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA Multi-GPU disabled.
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "MetaModes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 { ForceFullCompositionPipeline = On }"
[    34.393] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     CRT-0
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0 (boot)
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
[    34.787] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
[    34.788] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 760 (GK104) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    34.788] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[    34.788] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.04.ea.00.13
[    34.788] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[    34.796] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    34.796] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.796] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.807] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): connected
[    34.807] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[    34.807] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.807] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.807] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    34.808] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    34.810] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
[    34.810] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select+0+0{ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
[    34.810] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 2560 x 1440
[    34.874] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (108, 107); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    34.888] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    34.888] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    34.889] (II) NVIDIA: Using 12288.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
[    34.889] (II) NVIDIA:     access.
[    34.965] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select+0+0{ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
[    35.111] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    35.111] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
[    35.112] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    35.151] (**) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    35.151] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    35.151] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    35.151] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    35.151] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    35.151] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    35.212] (--) RandR disabled
[    35.299] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    35.354] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    35.354] (II) Indirect GLX disabled.
[    35.904] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    35.904] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.904] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    35.904] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    35.904] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    35.904]    compiled for 1.18.1, module version = 2.10.1
[    35.904]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    35.904]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 22.1
[    35.904] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    35.904] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    35.904] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    35.904] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    35.904] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    35.904] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.905] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    35.905] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    35.905] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.905] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.905] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    35.905] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    35.905] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    35.922] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    35.922] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.922] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    35.922] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    35.922] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    35.922] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    35.922] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    35.922] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.922] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    35.922] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    35.922] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.922] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.922] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    35.922] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    35.922] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    35.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event12)
[    35.923] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.923] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event13)
[    35.923] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.923] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.923] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event14)
[    35.923] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.923] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.924] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event15)
[    35.924] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.924] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.924] (II) config/udev: Adding input device RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device (/dev/input/event2)
[    35.924] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.924] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device'
[    35.924] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: always reports core events
[    35.924] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    35.924] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Vendor 0x24ae Product 0x2000
[    35.924] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found keys
[    35.924] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.924] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.0/0003:24AE:2000.0001/input/input5/event2"
[    35.924] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    35.924] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.924] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.924] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    35.924] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    35.924] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    35.925] (II) config/udev: Adding input device RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device (/dev/input/event3)
[    35.925] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    35.925] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    35.925] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device'
[    35.925] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: always reports core events
[    35.925] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Vendor 0x24ae Product 0x2000
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found 9 mouse buttons
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found relative axes
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found x and y relative axes
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found absolute axes
[    35.925] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Forcing absolute x/y axes to exist.
[    35.925] (--) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Found keys
[    35.925] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Configuring as mouse
[    35.925] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Configuring as keyboard
[    35.925] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: Adding scrollwheel support
[    35.925] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    35.925] (**) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    35.925] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-6/1-6.1/1-6.1:1.1/0003:24AE:2000.0002/input/input6/event3"
[    35.925] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    35.925] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    35.925] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    35.925] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    35.925] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    35.925] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    35.925] (II) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: initialized for relative axes.
[    35.925] (WW) evdev: RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: ignoring absolute axes.
[    35.925] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    35.925] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    35.926] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    35.926] (**) RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    35.926] (II) config/udev: Adding input device RAPOO RAPOO 2.4G Wireless Device (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    35.926] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.926] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.926] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Front (/dev/input/event7)
[    35.926] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.926] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.926] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Surround (/dev/input/event8)
[    35.926] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.926] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out CLFE (/dev/input/event9)
[    35.927] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.927] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line Out Side (/dev/input/event10)
[    35.927] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.927] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Front Headphone (/dev/input/event11)
[    35.927] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.927] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Rear Mic (/dev/input/event4)
[    35.927] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.927] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.927] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Front Mic (/dev/input/event5)
[    35.927] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.927] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    35.928] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA ATI SB Line (/dev/input/event6)
[    35.928] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    35.928] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    48.553] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    48.553] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.553] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): connected
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    48.565] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.943] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[    50.943] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.943] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.955] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): connected
[    50.955] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[    50.955] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.955] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    50.956] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.232] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[   533.232] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.232] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.251] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): connected
[   533.251] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[   533.251] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.251] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.252] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.261] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: disconnected
[   533.261] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CRT-0: 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.261] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): connected
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): Internal TMDS
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): AOC 2778X (DFP-0): 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal TMDS
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal TMDS
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): 
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[   533.280] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Comment: You could attach the output of `qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin supportInformation` as a pastebin link.

Comment: here the output with xrender http://vpaste.net/pIrhG

Comment: here the output with opengl 3.1 http://vpaste.net/6TdEo